# How to check a checkbox in PDF using nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, forms, pdf

I'm using fill-pdf (https://www.npmjs.com/package/fill-pdf) to fill a PDF form. Everything works fine, except for the checkboxes.
The PDF I'd like to fill is this one: https://www.formulaires.service-public.fr/gf/cerfa_14952.do

When I dump the data fields, I see there are several checkboxes:

- FieldName: topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].Case_?_cocher12[0]
- FieldName: topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].Case_?_cocher29[0]
- FieldName: topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].Case_?_cocher8[0]
- FieldName: topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].Case_?_cocher14[0]

When I set them to "1", "Yes", "checked", 1 or "On", it doesn't work.
Can somebody explain what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I managed to change the name of the field using https://www.pdfescape.com .
Indeed, the "?" was actually a "à", and fillpdf doesn't seem to be able to handle this character.